# fugacity of gases and gaseous mixtures

Tags: thermodynamics

Is fugacity defined only for gases and gaseous solution.?
In many books it is given that fugacity is "effective pressure", what does it mean?
If it is applicable to liquids and liquid solutions then how that "effective" pressure is defined?

Comment: I don't see any reason why one couldn't use it for solutions and the gas/liquid phase case. In essence it describes the ratio between a the partial pressure of a real substance and that of an ideal gas at the same concentration.